# how to compare ctid in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, comparison

I am trying to learn SQL with postgresql . I want select specific row with respected ctid . how can I do that ?

when I ran following query :-

```
select ctid,* from t01 where ctid = (0,11);
```

I get this error :-

```
operator does not exist: tid = record
LINE 1: select ctid,* from t01 where ctid = (0,11)
                                          ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

So how can I compare ctids in (postgre)sql ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can simply use `= '(0,1)'`:

```
#= select ctid,* from t where ctid = '(0,1)';
┌───────┬───┐
│ ctid  │ i │
├───────┼───┤
│ (0,1) │ 1 │
└───────┴───┘
(1 row)
```

Comment: I think it is worth noting that `ctid` is a [`tid` (AKA tuple identifier)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-oid.html) whose string representation is a pair of numbers in parentheses.